# PowerShell Create Folder on Remote Server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

The following script does not add a folder to my remote server.  Instead it places the folder on My machine!  Why does it do it?  What is the proper syntax to make it add it?

```
$setupFolder = "c:\SetupSoftwareAndFiles"

$stageSrvrs | ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "Opening Session on $_"
  Enter-PSSession $_

  Write-Host "Creating SetupSoftwareAndFiles Folder"

  New-Item -Path $setupFolder -type directory -Force 

  Write-Host "Exiting Session"

  Exit-PSSession

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Enter-PSSession can be used only in interactive remoting scenario. You cannot use it as a part of a script block. Instead, use Invoke-Command:

```
$stageSvrs | %{
         Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock { 
             $setupFolder = "c:\SetupSoftwareAndFiles"
             Write-Host "Creating SetupSoftwareAndFiles Folder"
             New-Item -Path $setupFolder -type directory -Force 
             Write-Host "Folder creation complete"
         }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

UNC path works as well with New-Item

```
$ComputerName = "fooComputer"
$DriveLetter = "D"
$Path = "fooPath"
New-Item -Path \\$ComputerName\$DriveLetter$\$Path -type directory -Force
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I had to add `FileSystem::` before the UNC path. Ex: `FileSystem::\\servername\path\newfolder`

Answer (score 2):

For those who -ScriptBlock doesn't work, you can use this:

```
$c = Get-Credential -Credential 
$s = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.NewScriptBlock("mkdir c:\NewDir")
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC01 -ScriptBlock $s -Credential $c
```

Comment: Old thread but for anyone else running this way: When you say "ScriptBlock doesn't work", I think you may be running into the issue where local variables aren't passed to the remote session. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328690/how-do-i-pass-variables-with-the-invoke-command-cmdlet

Answer (score 0):

The following code will create a new folder on a remote server using server name specified in `$server`. The below code assumes credentials are stored in `MySecureCredentials` and setup beforehand. Simply call `createNewRemoteFolder "<Destination-Path>"` to create the new folder.

```
function createNewRemoteFolder($newFolderPath) {

    $scriptStr = "New-Item -Path $newFolderPath -type directory -Force"
    $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($scriptStr)

    runScriptBlock $scriptBlock
}


function runScriptBlock($scriptBlock) {

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $MySecureCreds -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Servers=Get-SPServer |?{ $_.Role -notlike "Invalid"}

foreach($Server in $Servers)
{
    $Machine=$Server.Address
    $Path= "SP Logs"
    $NewFolder="Trace2"
    $DL= "E"
    #Write-Host "Server name is = " $Server
    New-Item -Path \\$Machine\E$\$Path\$NewFolder -Force -ItemType Directory
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to provide a folder name from the client, @Freddie has given clever answer. But I find more easy to do following:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $credInvoke- 
Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { param ($folder) New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory } -ArgumentList @("C:\temp\my_new_folder")
```