# Remote powershell on server says argument for parameter is empty string

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, remote-access

I have a powershell script on machine A that uses `PSSession` to invoke a command on Machine B. Machine B has a powershell script which accepts 4 parameters. When I call this script with the 4 arguments as variables (which they MUST be), they are passed as empty strings/null. When I pass them as strings (For example `-Argument1 "Hello"`), that string will be passed as "Hello"  and not as NULL/empty string.

Can anyone tell me why these are not passed correctly and how to fix it?

The powershell version on the client is `5.1.17134.112`. The remote machine uses `5.1.14393.2248`. These versions have been obtained by running `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`.

The client is using `Windows 10 Pro 10.0.17134`. The server is using `Windows 2016 Datacenter 10.0.14393` and is run as a VM on Azure.

I have tried using `Script.ps1 -Argument1 $ClientArgument1 -Argument2 $ClientArgument2 ...` to pass variables AND to use `ArgumentList` to pass the values comma separated to the script but both these attempts resulted in things not being printed.

I have noticed that when I use `-Argument1 "Hello" -Argument2 $ClientArgument2 -Argument3 $ClientArgument3 -Argument4 $ClientArgument4`, the *Hello* DOES get printed.

#### Code

**Client that connects to the remote machine**

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

#Create credentials to log in
$URL = 'https://url.to.server:5986'
$Username = "username"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText 'password' -Force
$SecureString = $pass
$MySecureCreds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$SecureString

$ClientArgument1 = "Argument 1"
$ClientArgument2 = "Argument 2" 
$ClientArgument3 = "Argument 3" 
$ClientArgument4 = "Argument 4" 

#Create the remote PS session
$sessionOption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri $URL -Credential $MySecureCreds -SessionOption $sessionOption

#Call the remote script and pass variables
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Command {C:\Path\To\Script\On\Remote\Machine\Script.ps1 -Argument1 $ClientArgument1 -Argument2 $ClientArgument2 -Argument3 $ClientArgument3 -Argument4 $ClientArgument4}

#Note: Command is used because Command allows me to execute a script that is located on disk of the remote machine
```

**The called script of the remote machine**

```
param(
    [String]$Argument1,
    [String]$Argument2,
    [String]$Argument3,
    [String]$Argument4
)

Write-Host 'Results of the 4 parameters passed into this script:'

Write-Host $Argument1
Write-Host $Argument2
Write-Host $Argument3
Write-Host $Argument4

Write-Host "The results have been printed"
```

#### Expected and actual results

**Expected results:**

```
Results of the 4 parameters passed into this script:
Argument 1
Argument 2
Argument 3
Argument 4
The results have been printed
```

**Actual results**

```
Results of the 4 parameters passed into this script:




The results have been printed
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: The first thing I would suggest is to remove the `[string]` typing on the args. I don't know for a fact that this is the issue but it isn't necessary and I have seen forced typing do odd things in the past.

Comment: You're not scoping your parameters.  Use the `$using:` scope for remote commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass variables with the Invoke-Command cmdlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328690/how-do-i-pass-variables-with-the-invoke-command-cmdlet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what inside the scriptblock in a different scope as the rest of your script, the `$ClientArgument` variables are undefined inside the scriptblock. The easiest solution if you are using PowerShell 3 or newer is to use the `$using:` scope. Otherwise an argumentlist for the `Invoke-Command` would be required.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Command {C:\Path\To\Script\On\Remote\Machine\Script.ps1 -Argument1 $using:ClientArgument1 -Argument2 $using:ClientArgument2 -Argument3 $using:ClientArgument3 -Argument4 $using:ClientArgument4}
```

Comment: [`CTRL+F => USING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute it this way:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Command {

C:\Path\To\Script\On\Remote\Machine\Script.ps1 `
-Argument1 $args[0] -Argument2 $args[1] `
-Argument3 $args[2] -Argument4 $args[3]

} -ArgumentList $ClientArgument1,$ClientArgument2,$ClientArgument3,$ClientArgument4
```

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 you are wrong in that, the OP did not did it in the question, using `$args[0] etc.` will solve the problem, it just like the `$using` - fix the scoping issue

Comment: My bad.  I misread part of his question in hindsight.  Either way, it's a duplicate question that gets asked here every week.