# Logging off Remote user via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I know there are other ways (may be even easier) to get this done... my questions is why I'm getting an error when using a variable instead of a session ID (i.e. 1, 2, 3)

```
cls
$pc = Read-Host "Computer Name: "
echo $pc
Get-Service -Name WinRM -ComputerName $pc | Set-Service -Status Running
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock { quser }
$session = Read-Host "Session ID: "
$session = $session -as [int]
echo $session
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock { logoff $session }
```

if I run:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock { logoff 1 }
```

I get no error... any easy way to get it working with my current script?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I changed it to say:  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ArgumentList $session -ScriptBlock { logoff $session }   but getting same error... thank you...

Comment: Yeah that's not what it's saying. If you want to pass the argument in, then you need to either use param block designating your own variable or `args[0]` - or like the answer there says use `$using:session`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

Use the using scope modifier

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock { logoff $using:session }
```

Use `-ArgumentList` with your own defined parameter. They are named the same here for convenience, the param statement could have any variable name*.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {Param($session) logoff $session} -argumentlist $session
```

Use `-ArgumentList` with the automatic args variable. Since it's the first argument you reference with `[0]`

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -ScriptBlock {logoff $args[0]} -argumentlist $session
```

*Any variable name that is not automatic or reserved

Comment: right on, works beautifully, thank you so much, any document or key words I can search to help me understand the why behind it or it really works? ty

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328690/how-do-i-pass-variables-with-the-invoke-command-cmdlet

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.1