# Need to restart multiple app pools for multiple servers

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-2.0

I am trying to restart multiple app pools from multiple servers.

Example:-
Server file - Server1,Server2;
AppPool file - AppPool1,AppPool2;
Server 1 should check AppPool1 and AppPool2.
Server 2 should check and restart AppPool1 and AppPool2.

```
$Fetch_Details_AppPools = [string[]](Get-Content D:\Users\VRao\Desktop\AUtomation\AppPoolName.csv)
$Fetch_Details_Server = [string[]](Get-Content D:\Users\VRao\Desktop\AUtomation\ServerName.txt)

foreach ($i in $Fetch_Details_Server) {
    foreach ($j in $i.$Fetch_Details_AppPools) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $i -ScriptBlock {
            Import-Module WebAdministration;
            If ((Get-WebAppPoolState(@using:j)).Value -eq "Stopped") {
                write-host("The App pool $using:j is getting started")
                Restart-WebAppPool -Name "$using:j"
            }
            else {
                Write-Host"$using:j is already in start state"
            }
            write-host("The App pool $using:j is started in $using:i")
        }
    }
}
```

Any errors or help on this?

Comment: `Invoke-Command` script blocks don't automatically see variables of surrounding scopes. Try: `Restart-WebAppPool -Name "$using:j"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass variables with the Invoke-Command cmdlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328690/how-do-i-pass-variables-with-the-invoke-command-cmdlet)

Comment: got it, This one is untested file, Do i need to change anything apart from this?

Comment: Please refer to this article https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/how-to-pass-arguments-for-remote-commands/ use param

Comment: @zett42 I have edited, like this ?

Comment: @BruceZhang Our clients will block modules for windows env in future.